# Using MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY for similar size subarrays but different starting position

Tags: mpi, sub-array

I want to transfer 3d blocks of data from one processor to another but their postions are different in both the processes. If I use MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY then do I need to define to two separate data types for send and receive or is their any way to put some offset in this derived data type?
It is confusing as the extent of the sub-array derived data type is the entire array so is it possible to use this data type in send and receive by passing the address of start of sub array instead of passing the start of the main array.

Currently I am defining separate data type for each starting location but this does not seems to be the right way do this I guess.

```
integer      :: sizes(1:3),subsizes(1:3),starts(1:3)
integer      :: sxL,exL,syL,eyL,szL,ezL,gc
integer      :: gtype(26)

sizes(1) = exL-sxL+2*gc+1
sizes(2) = eyL-syL+2*gc+1
sizes(3) = ezL-szL+2*gc+1

subsizes = gc

! Corner at i-1,j-1,k-1 (domain coordinates)
starts(1) = 0
starts(2) = 0
starts(3) = 0
call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY(3,sizes,subsizes,starts,MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN,&
                            realtype,gtype(13),ierr)
call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(gtype(13),ierr)
! Corner at i-1,j+1,k-1 (domain coordinates)
starts(1) = 0
starts(2) = eyL-syL+gc+1
starts(3) = 0
call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY(3,sizes,subsizes,starts,MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN,&
                            realtype,gtype(11),ierr)
call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(gtype(11),ierr)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post some code to show what you are trying to achieve. a [mcve] with a self test is ideal.

Comment: if the types only differ by `starts`, then you can use a single type starting at (1,1,1), and pass send/recv the first element of the array you want to send or receive.